# Why d3 line generator fails with the usage of scale around null values

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to understand why **`d3.line`** behaves differently around null values when combined with scale.

To elaborate, my dataset looks like this and it will always contain some `null`

```
const data = [
{ "x": 50, "y": 97.04013083865155 },
{ "x": 100, "y": null },
{ "x": 150, "y": 98.62594214598816 },
{ "x": 200, "y": 76.49419950954189 },
{ "x": 250, "y": 29.30639006661442 },
{ "x": 300, "y": 29.366842697148176 },
{ "x": 350, "y": 51.587600132998325 },
{ "x": 400, "y": null },
{ "x": 450, "y": null },
{ "x": 500, "y": 26.90860254816283 },
{ "x": 550, "y": null },
{ "x": 600, "y": 99.1622268038577 }
]
```

**No Scale +null**

If I want to generate a line, and **not use **`scale`**, I get the following**

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 1 DATA ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const data = [
    { "x": 50, "y": 97.04013083865155 },
    { "x": 100, "y": null },
    { "x": 150, "y": 98.62594214598816 },
    { "x": 200, "y": 76.49419950954189 },
    { "x": 250, "y": 29.30639006661442 },
    { "x": 300, "y": 29.366842697148176 },
    { "x": 350, "y": 51.587600132998325 },
    { "x": 400, "y": null },
    { "x": 450, "y": null },
    { "x": 500, "y": 26.90860254816283 },
    { "x": 550, "y": null },
    { "x": 600, "y": 99.1622268038577 }


]
height = 400,
    width = 720;

padding = {
    top: 70,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 70,
    right: 70
}


const boundHeight = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;
const boundWidth = width - padding.right - padding.left;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 2 CREATE SCALE ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, boundWidth])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.x))

const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([boundHeight, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.y))

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 3 SVG// ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
const svg = d3.select('svg')

svg
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'vBoxRect')
    .style("overflow", "visible")
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('fill', 'none')

//create BOUND rect -- to be deleted later
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'boundRect')
    .attr('x', `${padding.left}`)
    .attr('y', `${padding.top}`)
    .attr('width', `${boundWidth}`)
    .attr('height', `${boundHeight}`)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')



//create bound element
bound = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bound')
    .style('transform', `translate(${padding.left}px,${padding.top}px)`)

//constrcuct line generators

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////NO SCALE// /////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
noScale = d3.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    (data)


//no Scale
bound.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'Black-noScale')
    .attr('d', noScale)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')

console.log(noScale)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
<svg>
</svg>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <script src="next.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**With Scale +null**

However, if I want to generate a line, and **use **`scale`**, the generator *fails***

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 1 DATA ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const data = [
    { "x": 50, "y": 97.04013083865155 },
    { "x": 100, "y": null },
    { "x": 150, "y": 98.62594214598816 },
    { "x": 200, "y": 76.49419950954189 },
    { "x": 250, "y": 29.30639006661442 },
    { "x": 300, "y": 29.366842697148176 },
    { "x": 350, "y": 51.587600132998325 },
    { "x": 400, "y": null },
    { "x": 450, "y": null },
    { "x": 500, "y": 26.90860254816283 },
    { "x": 550, "y": null },
    { "x": 600, "y": 99.1622268038577 }


]
height = 400,
    width = 720;

padding = {
    top: 70,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 70,
    right: 70
}


const boundHeight = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;
const boundWidth = width - padding.right - padding.left;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 2 CREATE SCALE ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, boundWidth])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.x))

const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([boundHeight, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.y))

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 3 SVG// ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
const svg = d3.select('svg')

svg
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'vBoxRect')
    .style("overflow", "visible")
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('fill', 'none')

//create BOUND rect -- to be deleted later
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'boundRect')
    .attr('x', `${padding.left}`)
    .attr('y', `${padding.top}`)
    .attr('width', `${boundWidth}`)
    .attr('height', `${boundHeight}`)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')



//create bound element
bound = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bound')
    .style('transform', `translate(${padding.left}px,${padding.top}px)`)



//constrcuct line generators

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////WITH SCALE// ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

withScale = d3.line()
    .x(d => scaleX(d.x))
    .y(d => scaleY(d.y))
    (data)

bound.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'Orange-withScale')
    .attr('d', withScale)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'orange')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
    
console.log(withScale);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
<svg>
</svg>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <script src="next.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

On the other hand, the genrator works well with **defined** whether **scale used or not**

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 1 DATA ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const data = [
    { "x": 50, "y": 97.04013083865155 },
    { "x": 100, "y": null },
    { "x": 150, "y": 98.62594214598816 },
    { "x": 200, "y": 76.49419950954189 },
    { "x": 250, "y": 29.30639006661442 },
    { "x": 300, "y": 29.366842697148176 },
    { "x": 350, "y": 51.587600132998325 },
    { "x": 400, "y": null },
    { "x": 450, "y": null },
    { "x": 500, "y": 26.90860254816283 },
    { "x": 550, "y": null },
    { "x": 600, "y": 99.1622268038577 }


]
height = 400,
    width = 720;

padding = {
    top: 70,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 70,
    right: 70
}


const boundHeight = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;
const boundWidth = width - padding.right - padding.left;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 2 CREATE SCALE ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, boundWidth])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.x))

const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([boundHeight, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.y))

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 3 SVG// ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
const svg = d3.select('svg')

svg
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'vBoxRect')
    .style("overflow", "visible")
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('fill', 'none')

//create BOUND rect -- to be deleted later
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'boundRect')
    .attr('x', `${padding.left}`)
    .attr('y', `${padding.top}`)
    .attr('width', `${boundWidth}`)
    .attr('height', `${boundHeight}`)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')



//create bound element
bound = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bound')
    .style('transform', `translate(${padding.left}px,${padding.top}px)`)

//constrcuct line generators

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////NO SCALE// /////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

noScaleWithDefinedFilter = d3.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    .defined(d => d.y)
    (data.filter((a) => a.y !== null))

noScaleWithDefined = d3.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    .defined(d => d.y)
    (data)

//shows complete line
bound.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'Violet-noScale+defined+filter')
    .attr('d', noScaleWithDefinedFilter)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'violet')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
    .style('transform', 'translateY(50px)')

//does not show null Y
bound.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'Red-noScale+defined')
    .attr('d', noScaleWithDefined)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
    .style('transform', 'translateY(75px)')
    

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////WITH SCALE// /////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

withScaleWithDefined = d3.line()
    .x(d => scaleX(d.x))
    .y(d => scaleY(d.y))
    .defined(d => d.y)
    (data)

withScaleWithDefinedFilter = d3.line()
    .x(d => scaleX(d.x))
    .y(d => scaleY(d.y))
    .defined(d => d.y)
    (data.filter((a) => a.y !== null))

bound.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'Salmon-withScale+Defined+Filter')
    .attr('d', withScaleWithDefinedFilter)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'salmon')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')

bound.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'Blue-withScale+Defined')
    .attr('d', withScaleWithDefined)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
    .style('transform', 'translateY(-25px)')

console.log(noScaleWithDefinedFilter);
console.log(noScaleWithDefined);
console.log(withScaleWithDefined);
console.log(withScaleWithDefinedFilter);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
<svg>
</svg>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <script src="next.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I achieve, what the following does

```
const noScale = d3.line()
    .x(d => d.x)
    .y(d => d.y)
    (data)
```

but with scaling

```
const withScale = d3.line()
    .x(d => scaleX(d.x))
    .y(d => scaleY(d.y))
    (data)
```

Can this be achieved without destroying the data?

Comment: In your first case, the nulls are being treated as zeros. If that is what you want, just use  ternary operator in the function  `.y( d => d.y ? scaleY(d.y): scaleY(0) ) `

Comment: I tested out this suggestion and it does not scale at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design and documented: if you pass a `null` value to that linear scale it will return `undefined`, and obviously you cannot do anything with `undefined` inside the `d` attribute.

The solution for the scale itself is using `unknown`, which sets the *unknown* returned value to any value you want, for instance zero:

```
const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .unknown(0)
    etc...
```

If, on the other hand, you want to **skip** the null values, you have to change the line generator itself with `defined`, not the scale.

Here's your code with `unknown(0)`:

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 1 DATA ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const data = [
    { "x": 50, "y": 97.04013083865155 },
    { "x": 100, "y": null },
    { "x": 150, "y": 98.62594214598816 },
    { "x": 200, "y": 76.49419950954189 },
    { "x": 250, "y": 29.30639006661442 },
    { "x": 300, "y": 29.366842697148176 },
    { "x": 350, "y": 51.587600132998325 },
    { "x": 400, "y": null },
    { "x": 450, "y": null },
    { "x": 500, "y": 26.90860254816283 },
    { "x": 550, "y": null },
    { "x": 600, "y": 99.1622268038577 }


]
height = 400,
    width = 720;

padding = {
    top: 70,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 70,
    right: 70
}


const boundHeight = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;
const boundWidth = width - padding.right - padding.left;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 2 CREATE SCALE ////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const scaleX = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, boundWidth])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.x))

const scaleY = d3.scaleLinear()
    .unknown(0)
    .range([boundHeight, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.y))

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////// 3 SVG// ///////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
const svg = d3.select('svg')

svg
    .attr('xmlns', svgns)
    .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`)

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'vBoxRect')
    .style("overflow", "visible")
    .attr('width', `${width}`)
    .attr('height', `${height}`)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('fill', 'none')

//create BOUND rect -- to be deleted later
svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'boundRect')
    .attr('x', `${padding.left}`)
    .attr('y', `${padding.top}`)
    .attr('width', `${boundWidth}`)
    .attr('height', `${boundHeight}`)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'black')



//create bound element
bound = svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'bound')
    .style('transform', `translate(${padding.left}px,${padding.top}px)`)



//constrcuct line generators

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////WITH SCALE// ////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

withScale = d3.line()
    .x(d => scaleX(d.x))
    .y(d => scaleY(d.y))
    (data)

bound.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'Orange-withScale')
    .attr('d', withScale)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('stroke', 'orange')
    .attr('stroke-width', '2')
    
console.log(withScale);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
<svg>
</svg>
    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <script src="next.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```